# how to add fixed width for Y Axis labels

Tags: angular, highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

I am trying to add fixed width for y axis labels.is there any way to add?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N4NR.jpg)

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        width: '30px',
        fontSize: '10px',
        textOverflow: 'none'
      }
    }
  },
```

tried this but not working,
can we add any trailing spaces for labels or can we stop changing the labels width when i scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the following way:

```
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        width: '30px',
        fontSize: '10px',
        textOverflow: 'none'
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0g9dvzxa/

Comment: using this we cant add width more than text size.

Comment: Currently, this is the only option available. Please refer to the thread below for future updates, or feel free to leave a comment there:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20277